# Virtuemart Repeat Order

Tags: php, joomla, shopping-cart, virtuemart

The thing is that I would like to implement the following functionality to my site:
In the account settings - order details I would like to add a button that would add all the products from that very order to cart.
Now, I pretty much get it how the add to cart functionality is implemented on the flypage and browse page. I can't really get how should I pass multiple items to the add to cart function on order details page and how it'll be processed by ps_cart if an item is out of stock or is unpublished.
Here's the code of the add to cart form from browse page:

```
<form action="<?php echo $mm_action_url ?>index.php" method="post" name="addtocart" id="addtocart<?php echo $i ?>" class="addtocart_form" <?php if( $this->get_cfg( 'useAjaxCartActions', 1 ) && !$notify ) { echo 'onsubmit="handleAddToCart( this.id );return false;"'; } ?>>
    <?php echo $ps_product_attribute->show_quantity_box($product_id,$product_id); ?><br />
    <input type="submit" class="<?php echo $button_cls ?>" value="<?php echo $button_lbl    ?>" title="<?php echo $button_lbl ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="<?php echo  @$_REQUEST['category_id'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id[]" value="<?php echo $product_id ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="shop.cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="func" value="cartadd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="<?php echo $sess->getShopItemid() ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="set_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="adjust_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="master_product[]" value="" />
</form>
```

I wonder if I'd need to pass all of these to ps_cart?
I don't expect from any of you a completely ready extension, it would be great if you could point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

EDIT:
I was able to set up the add to cart button, now I have to pass the needed data.
It would be great if it would work with at least one item, then I'd start thinking how to alter the code.

EDIT 2:
I was able to make it work flawlessly for one product. But how can I pass multiple Product Id's and their quantities to the add to cart function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code in ps_cart already has a loop to iterate through multiple product IDs that are sent to the cart. From the look of the code there, I would simple put all of the product IDs you want to add to the cart in to prod_id array. You will notice that prod_id, set_price, adjust_price, and master_product are all arrays in the form. My guess is that you will need to put in those values for each product you want to add and ps_cart will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks,I've noticed that,it works.It will add to cart the products specified in prod_id array, but it won't update on the second click of add to cart, it says that the cart has been updated but the quantity of products is the same, now I don't no, may be it's even for the best as it won't stack the order. There's another problem, if you already have product "X" for example in your cart and you try to add it again with this function it doesn't update it's quantity, but clones it, thus giving two product "X". Is there a way to call the reset function from ps_cart before calling the add function?

Comment: The cloning thing is now gone. I noticed that when you pass the quantity[] array it assigns the first quantity to the product with the least id and so on. Is there a way to specify which quantity should be assigned to which product id?

Comment: That will probably take some customization, I am pretty sure it's just looping through the cart until it matches the product ID.

Comment: I was able to fix it, if you pass the product's id in pair with quantity, they get assigned to each other. Thanks for your time!

Comment: That's good to know, that seems like a handy feature. You should package it up and sell the extension.

Comment: Hi, I edited the prod_id[] like this <input type="hidden" name="prod_id[]" value="235,244,687" />, is this the right way? because its not working for me, it only adds the first item

Comment: How are you setting the additional product IDs?